# Vuejs conditional AppBar

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, toolbar, back-button, appbar

In Vuetify, what is the best way to manage differenly styled appbars for various pages?
And how to enable **back** button instead of hamburger icon programatically?
Example: There are 5 screens, 2 of them have separate controls in app bar than the rest.

Comment: Please show us some examples you've tried your self, then we'll gladly help you solve any issues you run into.

Comment: For now I just could thought of rendering them based on current route `<v-card v-if="showAppBar" class="overflow-hidden">
      <v-app-bar...`

Answer (score 1):

For the question of coloring the app bar, if you're using the router, you can add a meta tag "color", then set v-app-bar's color property to something to the effect of 
`:color="$route.meta && $route.meta.color || 'blue-grey'"`, where blue-grey is the fallback color. Your route would look something like:

```js
{
  path: '/mycoolpath',
  component: MyCoolComponent,
  meta: {
     //other route meta...
     color: 'blue'
  }
}
```

For the question of enabling Back, just replace the app-bar-nav-icon with the appropriate [icon name](https://materialdesignicons.com/) (`mdi-arrow-left`, likely) and change it's @click to `$router.go(-1)` ([further reading on routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-go-n))

Comment: Thanks, we can also set the meta to decide whether the screen has back button or menu icon